# Symfony : vich/uploader-bundle 1.6.2 : config yml

Tags: symfony, vichuploaderbundle

I try to configure Vich using only YML and face to a problem.
I create declaration file (path: src/My/GreatBundle/Resources/config/vich_uploader/Media.yml) :

```
My\GreatBundle\Entity\Media:
    image:
        mapping: image_mapping
        filename_property: file_name
```

Create the entity media (path: src/My/GreatBundle/Entity/Media.php) :

```
<?php
namespace My\GreatBundle\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;

class Media{
    private $id;
    public function getId(){
        return $this->id;
    }

    protected $file_name;
    protected $image;

    public function setFileName($fileName){
        $this->file_name = $fileName;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getFileName(){
        return $this->file_name;
    }

    public function setImage(File $image){
        $this->image = $image;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getImage(){
        return $this->image;
    }
}
```

And finally create form (path: src/My/GreatBundle/Entity/Form/Type/MediaType.php) :

```
<?php
namespace My\GreatBundle\Entity\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

use Symfony\Component\Form\ChoiceList\Loader\CallbackChoiceLoader;

use My\GreatBundle\Entity\Media;

use Vich\UploaderBundle\Form\Type\VichImageType;

class MediaType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options){
        $builder
            ->add('image', VichImageType::class, [
                'required' => false,
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver){
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
             'data_class' => Media::class,
        ));
    }

    public function getName(){
        return 'my_great_type_media';
    }
}
```

An idea what is miss ? I have this message :

```
The class "My\GreatBundle\Entity\Media" is not uploadable. If you use annotations to configure VichUploaderBundle, you probably just forgot to add `@Vich\Uploadable` on top of your entity. If you don't use annotations, check that the configuration files are in the right place. In both cases, clearing the cache can also solve the issue.
```

Obviously I have clear cache.

Edit 1 : config.yml

```
vich_uploader:
    db_driver: orm
    mappings:
        image:
            uri_prefix: /media
            upload_destination: '%kernel.root_dir%/../uploads/media'
            delete_on_remove: true
            delete_on_update: false
            inject_on_load: false
            namer:
                service: vich_uploader.namer_property
                options: { property: 'id' }
```

Comment: Can you add your config.yml ?

Comment: config.yml add.
I try to set invalid syntax in the vich_uploader/Media.yml but it's look like if it what's not load (in spite I respect the directory name like say in documentation)

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED:**

As I can see, in your config stands that your filename_property is called **file_name**, but your form is using property **image** as filename property.

Also, in your `Media.yml` file you are using mapping name called **image_mapping** but in `config.yml` your mapping is named **image**.

I don't know the reason why you are avoiding annotations, but the life gets much easier when you use them :)

There is a related issue to this, so check [How to configure VichUploader in entity mapped by yml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24658894/how-to-configure-vichuploader-in-entity-mapped-by-yml)

Comment: I try to write invalid syntax but yml seems not recognized ! :(
I prefer YML for clarity when I use, because reading Annotation is like reading alien language, and as I began with yml, I think it's more consistent to continue in yml.